# Spring cloud config local and remote repositories for different profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to setup my application with multiple repositories - a local file based one for development/testing purpose and a remote git repo for production.

I am using the following yaml for this purpose -

```
spring:
  application:
    name: localRepoConfig
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          repos:
            development:
              pattern:
                - '*/development'
                - '*/staging'
              uri: https://github.com/development/config-repo          
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/config
server:
  port: 8888
```

This is not working however, the following works for the local repo -

```
spring:
  application:
    name: localRepoConfig
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/config
server:
  port: 8888
```

I have not been able to make the two repositories function, after following the Spring documentation and a few posts here.
Would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Corrected your formatting. Normally you only use the ` when you are doing a single line code. Multi-line code should be indented 4 spaces to make it show up as a block of code.

Comment: +1 for the idea: > a local file based one for development/testing purpose and a remote git repo for production.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with the following config in bootstrap.yml -

`spring:
  application:
    name: localRepoConfig
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/config
server:
  port: 8888`

`---`

`spring:

  profiles: development
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
server:
  port: 8989`

I am able to switch between the native and development profiles now.
The following guide was quite helpful -
kubecloud.io/guide-spring-cloud-config/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation on [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_environment_repository) it sounds like native and git are mutually exclusive and that you can't use both for a single config server.

Comment: Thanks for responding Shawn. 
Is there no other way of having the two configurations, such that I can switch between them with different profiles .. ?